# PHP preg_match: multiple group matches with + or * modifier don't appear in result?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

If I do this in PHP:

```php
$str = "abc pqrs-1/2&3uvw xyz";
preg_match( "/([a-z]+)([^0-9a-z][0-9])+([a-z]+)/" , $str , $m );
```

The resulting matches in `$m` will be:

```
[0] => "pqrs-1/2&3uvw"
[1] => "pqrs"
[2] => "&3"
[3] => "uvw"
```

Note how the `([^0-9a-z][0-9])+` part, which is supposed to catch "one non-alphanumeric character followed buy one digit" one or more times, has the `+` modifier *outside* the parentheses.

Obviously the subject string `$str` contains 3 matches for this pattern: `-1` and `/2` and `&3` but it only remembers the **last** one.

Is there a way to somehow catch them all?

I have tried `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` but that will only find multiple matches if the *entire* regular expression is matched more than once in the subject string.

To verbalize the meaning of my regular expression:

1. one or more letters
2. one or more of: a non-alphanumeric char followed by a digit
3. one or more letters

So for the above example string I would expect the result to be something like this:

```
[0] => "pqrs-1/2&3uvw"
[1] => "pqrs"
[2] => [ "-1" , "/2" , "&3" ]
[3] => "uvw"
```

But no matter what I try, I can't get it to also give the `-1` and `/2` matches?

Comment: When you repeat a capture group, the previous match content is overwritten.

Comment: Preg-match the string using `"/([a-z]+)((?:[^0-9a-z][0-9])+)([a-z]+)/"` and then preg-match-all the `$matches[2]` with `'/[^0-9a-z][0-9]/'`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew interesting, I was not familiar with the `?:` notation. Just found out about [non-capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match repeated substrings with repeated capturing groups. Instead, you need to do that using a two-step approach:

- Use `/([a-z]+)((?:[^0-9a-z][0-9])+)([a-z]+)/` regex to match and capture with `((?:[^0-9a-z][0-9])+)` *all* the repetitions of the `(?:[^0-9a-z][0-9])` pattern
- Then, use `preg_match_all` with the group pattern, `'/[^0-9a-z][0-9]/'`.

[PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/JI3HW):

```
$str = "abc pqrs-1/2&3uvw xyz";
if (preg_match('~([a-z]+)((?:[^0-9a-z][0-9])+)([a-z]+)~', $str, $matches)) {
    preg_match_all('~[^0-9a-z][0-9]~', $matches[2], $x);
    $matches[2] = $x[0];
}
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => pqrs-1/2&3uvw
    [1] => pqrs
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => -1
            [1] => /2
            [2] => &3
        )

    [3] => uvw
)
```